# Handle java inheritance in json

Tags: json

My class is as below:

```
    class A
    {
      private B b;
      private String id;
      //setter and getter
    }
    class B
    {
      private String name;
      //setter and getter
    }
    class C extends B
    {
      private String email;
      //setter and getter
    }
```

My Json is as below:

```
{
  "name":"Sample",
  "id":2,
  "email":"support@abd.com"
}
```

Now when I try to deserialise my json into a java object, I get:

> org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "email"

Please let me know how I could solve this.

Comment: Please show HOW you try to deserialize it

Comment: Also how you serialize it. In the json, there's no mention of it being of type `C`. Do you, as a human, think it should be deserialized as C? Based on what?

Comment: {
"type": "com.test.Bird", 
  "animal" : {
    "name": "bird"
  }
}

Comment: public class Animal {
    private String name;
    private String diet;
}


public class Bird extends Animal {
    private long wingspan;
}

Comment: http://www.copper-arrow.com/blog/java-json-serializing-and-de-serializing-polymorphic-objects

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you are handling deserializing the shared nodes in the base class, and the nodes specific to your class b/c in their own respective classes. If you are handling deserialization in your top level class, it won't recognize a unique property in an inheriting class.

It's difficult to see where you are going wrong without seeing your individual classes.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to deserialize from top level, ie from class A

Comment: Right - and that is why you are getting an error. The best advice I can give without seeing your classes, is to handle the serialization of each inside their respective classes.  If your object has an email, for example, serialize that in class C.  Because the classes are slightly different, the serialization needs to be handled slightly different. Hence the inheritance :)